# Squid delay pools

Tags: squid

I am trying to set my Squid 3.1 to make use of delay pools to stop people from hogging our internet connection.  I have an proxy server running Ubuntu 12.04 with Squid 3.1.

I have 450 PC's connecting to the proxy with about 980 users.  Not all connecting at the same time.  So far everything has been working great.  My only problem is that I get some people that would sit the whole day watching YouTube videos and thus pulling the overall speed down.  I got this how-to from this site:

[Limiting Bandwidth](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netos/article.php/10951_3352971_2/Rein-In-Your-Bandwidth-Hogs-with-Squid-Proxying.htm)

I have implemented it, but I am not sure if I have everything in my squid.conf file right, according to this how-to.

My squid.conf files looks like this

The delay pool:

```
delay_pools 1
delay_class 1 3
delay_parameters 1 -1/-1 -1/-1 125/1000
delay_initial_bucket_level 100
```

ACL section

```
acl flash rep_mime_type video/x-flv
acl block_site dstdomain "/etc/squid3/blocked"
acl biz_network src 10.0.0.0/12
acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl biz_hours time M T W H F 07:00-21:00

http_access allow manager localhost

http_access deny block_site
http_reply_access deny flash
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
delay_access 1 allow biz_network


http_access allow ncsa_users biz_network biz_hours
```

Do I uncomment :

```
http_access allow ncsa_users biz_network biz_hours
```

and replace it with

```
delay_access 1 allow ncsa_users biz_network biz_hours
```

At the moment I have the YouTube site blocked via Squid, but with this being an educational institution it is not the best way, as some lecturers need YouTube access.

Can someone help?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken delay youtube videos is a mess, since they don't use flash but HTML5 for most.

Answer (score -1):

I think Squid 3.1 or later does not support delay pools.....u should use previous versions like 2.6/2.7

Comment: Untrue. Delay pool configuration is perfectly available since 2.2 including 3.x versions. See http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/